# NSDateFormatter in loop

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsdateformatter

I am having some issues with the following function. I have a dictionary with an array of date strings. I would like to loop through them and generate an NSDate object for each string. An example of the date string would be 20Z01NOV2011, where 20Z indicates 8:00 Zulu time, followed by the day,month, year.To make the date extraction easier, I remove the Z and insert a space.
The date formatter seems to work fine the first loop iteration, however fails on the subsequent iterations, however the input string format seems to be fine. Im not sure if there is a memory issue, and the string or formatter needs to be cleared, but I could use a hand correcting it.

```
    NSDateFormatter *timeFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [timeFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH ddMMMyyyy"];
    NSMutableArray *tempDates = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[[dict objectForKey:@"time"] count]];
    NSMutableArray *tempDateStrings = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[[dict objectForKey:@"time"] count]];

    for (int i=0; i < [[dict objectForKey:@"time"] count]; ++i) {
        NSString *dateString = [[[dict objectForKey:@"time"] objectAtIndex:i] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"Z" withString:@" "];
        NSDate *date = [timeFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
        [tempDates addObject:date];
        [timeFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE h:mm a"];
        [tempDateStrings addObject:[timeFormatter stringFromDate:date]];

    }

    [dict setObject:tempDateStrings forKey:@"dateStrings"];
    [dict setObject:tempDates forKey:@"dateObjects"];
```

Comment: Why are you storing the dates twice? You store them as NSDates here in your parsing function, that should be good enough until the function when they are displayed. When they are displayed you can then format them in a pleasant way. Plus that will save you changing your format which as bshirley pointed out is why your code is failing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Side note, I think you should remove the index from the iteration entirely:

Also, you're resetting the formatter inside the loop…

```
for (NSString *dateString in [dict objectForKey:@"time"]) {
    dateString = [dateString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"Z" withString:@" "];
    NSDate *date = [timeFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
    [tempDates addObject:date];
    [timeFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE h:mm a"]; // RESETING DATE FORMAT - SECOND ITERATION WILL FAIL
    [tempDateStrings addObject:[timeFormatter stringFromDate:date]];

}
```

I suspect you want two formatters, ONE to read the string input, and a SECOND to output the value into the format you like.

Comment: Yep, thats definitely the problem. Pretty obvious now. Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 0):

It fails on subsequent iterations because you MODIFIED THE FORMAT near the bottom of the loop.  What you probably want is two separate formatters, one for one format and one for the other, so you don't have to switch formats back and forth.